# Why are Vue DOM changes so slow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs3, svelte

I have a list of 2000 input checkboxes. When selecting them all at once there is noticeable delay (and browser freeze) of about 2 seconds. This seems to be the case for Vue and React, but not for Svelte or jQuery or vanilla.

With 5k+ checkboxes it becomes a very annoying 3-5 seconds blocker...

Why is the re-rendering taking so long?

How can I overcome this update delay with Vue.js?

(The solutions of paginate or lazy-load are not really solving the problem; they are avoiding it.)

Below is the code in Vue followed by the same example in Svelte.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const items = ref(Array.from({length: 2000}, (v, k) => k));
let selected = ref([]);
function selectAll() {
  selected.value = items.value.map(i => i);
}
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="selectAll">
    Select all
  </button>
  <button @click="selected = []">
    Select none
  </button>
  <label v-for="n in items">
    <input v-model="selected" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ n }}
  </label>
</template>

<style>
  label {
    display: block;
    }
</style>
```

[Vue SFC link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Svelte:

```
<script>
    let items = Array.from({length: 2000}, (v, k) => k);
    let selected = [];
    function selectAll() {
        selected = items.map(i => i);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={selectAll}>
    Select all
</button>
<button on:click="{() => selected = []}">
    Select none
</button>
{#each items as n, i}
<label>
    <input type=checkbox bind:group={selected} value={n}>
    {n}
</label>
{/each}

<style>
  label {
    display: block;
    }
</style>
```

[Svelte REPL link](https://svelte.dev/repl/b57041825116473081b98d49a2f5b3cb?version=3.47.0)

Comment: Memoization could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. The reason of slowly changes**

```html
<label v-for="n in items">
    <input v-model="selected" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ n }}
</label>
```

You use v-model selected, but selected is array and you put a whole array of 2000 values in the v-model of each of the 2000 inputs, which is a lot and that's why the browser is waiting

**2. Solving**

You can use in input

```html
<label v-for="n in items">
    <input v-model="selected[n]" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ n }}
</label>
```

and you can change selectAll function in script

```js
function selectAll() {
    selected = items.map(i => true);
}
```

Comment: `which is a lot`, but is it? It is not a lot for vanilla or Svelte. In fact, vanilla can easily handle 10K

Comment: `you put a whole array of 2000 values in the v-model`. That is the recommended way for group of checkboxes https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox I agree your way is much faster.

Comment: With handling not problam, but rendering another thing!

Comment: If you button clicked, then rendered somesing like that

Comment: <label>
    <input v-model="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ 0 }}
</label>

<label v-for="n in items">
    <input v-model="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ 1 }}
</label>

<label v-for="n in items">
    <input v-model="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]" type="checkbox" :value="n">
    {{ 2 }}
</label>
...

Comment: Why you wont this?

Comment: Change `selectAll` to `selected.value = items.value.map(i => true);` to get it run. Works well!